# Efficient way of manipulating a disk subsection of square array

Tags: python, c++, containers

I am currently coding numerical simulations of a lattice for a physics project.

I am used to manipulating square subsections of lattices where a variable or degree of freedom sits at each site of the lattice by using a 2d array.

Now, I would like to move to more general subsections, especifically circular ones just as in the picture below:

[image: circular subsection in square lattice]

Only the red area would by dynamical (evolve in time) and so the outside of it would not need to be stored in memory.

I am wondering if you know of an efficient and somewhat natural container for holding such objects.

My only idea is to store the whole thing **plus** a flat boolean array telling me for each site if it inside or outside, but that could become a huge waste of computational time later.

ps: I will code that in Python and/or c++

Comment: So... what have you tried?  Please post some code.

Comment: A [sparse matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) might be something to consider here. You would just need to initialize it with zero values for sites outside the area. But if you provide some more info on the type of simulation you're running then there might be some better tailored solutions out there for your use case.

Comment: If you know the bounding-box extent of the subsection, you only need store the lattice values of sites within that. Then use your supplementary boolean array (bitmap) idea to identify which of the values in it are the ones of interest.